# Trying to change the data-disabled value of a span element using tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

There is a website that contains the following span element inside few divs and other spans:

```
<span jsslot="" class="sx2eZe QAAyWd aKIhz OWB6Me" jsaction="uuup1e:W0gBYb" data-value="4" data-disabled="true" role="option" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="true">
```

If I inspect the element manually with the browser and change data-disable to false then I have a new option in the website.  It's tedious to do it manually every time so I want to create a tampermonkey script for that:

```
(function() {
var elmLink = document.getElementById('sx2eZe QAAyWd aKIhz OWB6Me');
    elmLink.setAttribute('data-disabled', 'false')
})();
```

But it doens't work I still need to inspec tthe element manually and change it to false to get it working

Comment: You're using `getElementById` with class names, what did you expect? :) Maybe you were looking to use `document.querySelector('.sx2eZe.QAAyWd.aKIhz.OWB6Me')`? By the way, these classes seem to have been autogenerated at compile time. Next time the website is updated, these classes might be different and break your code

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Changed it as per your advice but still nothing. I think that the problem is that the span element changes after the website is loaded so the tampermonkey script doesn't manage to get the changed don

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` expects an ID. To select an element using multiple class names, `querySelector` is more appropriate (you pass a CSS selector to it):

```
var elmLink = document.querySelector('.sx2eZe.QAAyWd.aKIhz.OWB6Me');
```

If this does not work because the element does not exist on page load, you can wait for it before using it. Here is an example:

```js
// Simulating an element created after a delay (just for the demo)
setTimeout(() => {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = "sx2eZe QAAyWd aKIhz OWB6Me";
  span.setAttribute('data-disabled', 'true');
  span.innerHTML = 'disabled: true';
  document.body.appendChild(span);
}, 400);

// Add this function to your script
function waitForElement(selector) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
      var el = document.querySelector(selector);
      if (el) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve(el);
      }
    }, 50);
  });
}

// And use it like so
waitForElement('.sx2eZe.QAAyWd.aKIhz.OWB6Me')
.then(elmLink => {
  elmLink.setAttribute('data-disabled', 'false');
  elmLink.innerHTML = 'disabled: false';
});
```